# Gamma Adjustment on the HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

I found a way to increase the gamma, but no way to decrease it! [This article](http://thecryptmag.com/Online/57/imgproc_6.html) states a formula for increasing the gamma. The formula works for increasing the gamma but not for decreasing, even if I apply the reduction on a new instance of the canvas. I tried redrawing the canvas and using a negative value for gamma calculation, but I don't get my original canvas back.

```
//For increasing, I tried
gamma = 0.5;
gammacorrection = 1/gamma;
r = Math.pow(255 * (r / 255), gammacorrection);
g = ...
b = ...

//For decreasing
gamma = -0.5;
gammacorrection = 1/gamma;
r = Math.pow(255 * (r / 255), gammacorrection);
g = ...
b = ...
```

First part works. Second doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no negative value for gamma. Ideally this value will range between `0.01` and `7.99`. So reverting back the gamma to the original value should be possible either by creating a new canvas instance with the original values of the image, then instantiating it, or either by creating a pool of pixels with the original image and reverting back to it.

I wrote a script how would i construct the algorithm for gamma reduction.

```js
var gamma = 0.5;
var gammaCorrection = 1 / gamma;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   

function GetPixelColor(x, y) {   
    var index = parseInt(x + canvas.width * y) * 4;
    var rgb = {
        r : imageData.data[index + 0],
        g : imageData.data[index + 1],
        b : imageData.data[index + 2]
    };

    return rgb;
}

function SetPixelColor(x, y, color) {
    var index = parseInt(x + this.width * y) * 4;
    var data = imageData.data;

    data[index+0] = color.r;
    data[index+1] = color.g;
    data[index+2] = color.b;
};


for (y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
     for (x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
         var color = GetPixelColor(x, y)
         var newRed   = Math.pow(255 * (color.r / 255), gammaCorrection);
         var newGreen = Math.pow(255 * (color.g / 255), gammaCorrection);
         var newBlue  = Math.pow(255 * (color.b / 255), gammaCorrection);

         var color = {
             r: newRed,
             g: newGreen,
             b: newBlue
         }

         SetPixelColor(x, y, color);
     }
}
```

I don't know how the application should adjust the gamma value, but i suppose it's done with a value adjuster. If so you should adjust the gamma value dynamically giving the min and max range. I didn't tested the code, this wasn't my scope, but the idea is hopefully clear.

**EDIT:**
To understand the principle of gamma correction first how about to define the gamma instead.

Gamma is the monitor particularity altering the pixels input. Gamma correction is the act of inverting that process for linear RGB values so that the final output remains linear. For example, if you calculated the light intensity of an object is 0.5, you don't store the result as 0.5 in the pixel. Store it as `pow(0.5, 1.0/2.2) = 0.73`. When you send 0.73 to the monitor, it will apply a gamma on the value and produce `pow(0.73, 2.2) = 0.5`, which is what you want. To do this, you apply the inverse gamma function.

`o=pow(i, 1.0/gamma)`

Where

`o` is the output value.

`i` is the input value.

`gamma` is the gamma value used by your monitor.

So the gamma correction is nothing else than the rise of input value to the power of inverse of gamma. So to restore the gamma to the original value you apply the formula before the gamma correction has been applied.

[image]
[image]

The blue line represents the inverse gamma curve you need to apply to your pixels before they're sent to the monitor. When your monitor applies its gamma curve (red line) to the pixels, the result is a linear line (green line) that represents your intended RGB pixel values.

Comment: I am creating a new instance of the canvas with the image redrawn! Does your code increase/decrease gamma?

Comment: If I raise the gamma with an adjustment of 0.5, how will decrease it by the same adjustment, for the next redraw?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation man! Its really helpful!
Sorry, call me dumb or call it spoon feeding, I still don't understand, how I am going to apply a gamma of 0.5 to an image and reduce the gamma of the same image (redrawn brand new) by 0.5 to get back my original image since I want to show it visually. Could you please simplify it down to a simple formula for increase and decrease, which I can call on my canvas using plus/minus buttons for raise/reduce gamma?

Comment: Setting gamma to initial `1` does not solve your problem? Or putting another way: if you have and initial value for the gamma, increasing it's value with an amount of percentage does not alter the output with the same amount when you decrease it with the same percentage?

Comment: Oh yeah man! I set the initial gamma to 1, and manipulated that value with 0.1 rise/fall on my button clicks! Kept the lower limit as 0 and higher limit as 2. Works well mate... Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21647/discussion-between-rutwick-gangurde-and-esimov)

Comment: Yeah man... not just gamma, but you also helped me fix my code for brightness and contrast adjustment! Thanks a ton bro! :D

Comment: I would suggest precomputing a table of 256 values, from 0 to 255, and use that as a lookup on a per-pixel basis, to avoid doing all that math on each and every pixel.

Comment: `Math.pow(255 * (color.r / 255), gammaCorrection);` should be 255 * Math.pow(color.r / 255, gammaCorrection);

Answer (score 5):

For sake of completeness here's a working piece of code

```
async function adjustGamma(gamma) {
    const gammaCorrection = 1 / gamma;
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasOutput');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const data = imageData.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        data[i] = 255 * Math.pow((data[i] / 255), gammaCorrection);
        data[i+1] = 255 * Math.pow((data[i+1] / 255), gammaCorrection);
        data[i+2] = 255 * Math.pow((data[i+2] / 255), gammaCorrection);
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

Here the function adjusts the gamma based on the formula in the Article linked by OP on the Canvas with id "canvasOutput"

Comment: Thanks for answering a 6 year old question! :) I had worked around it based on a solution above, but I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 4):

There is no negative gamma correction. You should save the original values and use them when making gamma changes, and set gamma to `1.0` to revert back to the original.

Also note that you have the wrong order of operations (exponents come before multiplication).

```
var originals = { r: r, g: g, b: b };

// increase
gamma = 0.5;
gammacorrection = 1/gamma;
r = 255 * Math.pow(( originals.r / 255), gammacorrection);
g = ...
b = ...

// revert to original
gamma = 1;
gammacorrection = 1/gamma;
r = 255 * Math.pow(( originals.r / 255), gammacorrection);
g = ...
b = ...
```

Comment: Yes, @JJJ gave a continuous function. This should be the accepted answer since the math is actually correct.